# Change iframe video id on click

Tags: jquery, youtube-iframe-api

I have a number of links with different youtube videos I would like to show in a modal. When the user clicks the link, the video id should update from the iframe api and load the modal.

http://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/7308/

## html

```
<a id='video-player-1' href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="VDB65S6rCC0" >Open Modal 1</a>
<a id='video-player-2' href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="1roy4o4tqQM" >Open Modal 2</a>
<a id='video-player-3' href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="Q3w7Fz6KFa8" >Open Modal 3</a>
```

## Javascript

```
$('#video-player-1').click(function(e) {
    var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
    var x = new String(bookId);
    player.loadVideoById(x);
    alert("HEELO");
    });

$( "#video-player-2" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

However, my on click events to not seem to get called. Nor does my video id update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script />` tag is above the elements on the page. When the event handlers are created the elements do not exist on the page. You can fix this by wrapping them in *jQuery's* [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler (which is an alais for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

**Basic Syntax:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#video-player-1').click(function(e) {
         var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
        var x = new String(bookId);
        player.loadVideoById(x);
        alert("HEELO");
        });

    $( "#video-player-2" ).click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });

});
```

**Short Hand Syntax:**

```
$(function () {

    $('#video-player-1').click(function(e) {
         var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book-id');
        var x = new String(bookId);
        player.loadVideoById(x);
        alert("HEELO");
        });

    $( "#video-player-2" ).click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });

});
```

**Alternative:**

As another alternative, you can add these handlers in a new `<script />` tag located right before the closing `</body>` tag. With this method, you can eliminate the call to `$(document).ready` and use your existing code as the elements have already been populated in the DOM by the time the handlers are created.

**Updated Working Fiddle Example:** [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/7311/)

Comment: It works, thank you, any recommendation for moving all the JS code to a separate file?